# Logout with Android and PHP

Tags: php, android, session, logout

I have **web(PHP) and Android** based applications. I have a coloumn **isLoggedIn** in users table. But sometimes the apps don't work properly. It logout, but isLoggedIn hasn't set to false yet. So, my questions are:
1. Condition when PHP **session is timeout** so i could update isLoggedIn,
2. Condition when Android app is **closed/killed** that causes by whatever(crash or OS) so i could update isLoggedIn coloumn.

Comment: Someone just asked that very question a day or two ago. Answers are still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to retreive the tokens from the response generated and store it locally on the application..

You can find more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/).

And finally check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005460/android-login-with-token-session-like-user-logins-and-stays-in-session-until-lo) of the question on stackoverflow which i have reffered

Answer (score -2):

My mistake, edited my answer. I suggest make the isLoggedin for web only and make a new session for android using sharedpreferences so it won't have any conflicts.

Comment: Yeah i know the part with sql, but the problem is i dont know what condition is in php and android. I just set it on logout button. The problem is when the app is killed, i dont know how to call the that condition. So it causes i cant login if the app was killed.

Comment: Don't restrict their login with isLoggedIn then. Famous apps like facebook can be logged in mobile / web at the same time.

Comment: But i want to restrict user login in my apps. User just could login 1 time in 1 device to improve my apps security in my thesis...

Comment: Ok if that's the case. Stick with isLoggedIn with both php and android running for it. Now for app crashes you need to do some try/catch and logging, for app exiting you need to check onBackPressed as well as the finish(); statements you made and make the requests/queries for isLoggedin there...